# Android library .aar file contents

Tags: android, gradle, repository, nexus, aar

We are evaluating a third party SDK to integrate with our Android app but the problem is that the third party company doesn't have any repo (eg: Maven) support. They are providing an Android module that needs to be imported (which consists of several .aar files, .java files, .manifest file and few assets). I don't understand why they are not providing a single .aar file that includes all of these, are there any technical challenges in doing that? The problem at our side is that we are using a local Nexus repository and we will have to manually upload this module and unzip the contents every time we do a build. Looking for any ideas on how to deal with this problem, thanks.

Comment: Unless the bare Java files, manifest, and such are example code, they could have created an AAR for those items. Transitive dependency metadata is in the repository POM, though -- no POM, no transitive dependency info. But... why do you have to unzip this stuff on every build? I can see having to do that for every update that the third party ships.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I mentioned the unzipping just because it adds to our build time when we do a clean build. We already use many third party SDKs so didn't want to increase the build time further. We already asked them to provide a Maven repo but they said they dont have any plans for now. In the worst case we will ask them to provide a single aar file that includes everything. The Java files, Manifest files are not example code and they are needed to include the SDK